# Return character instead of integer

Tags: mysql

Is there any way in MySQL to return a character when I give integer as input?

For example

```
Value     Returns
-----------------
1         A
2         B
3         C
4         D
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`SELECT char(int)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char), but please note it will only work for 27 characters, before returning `[ \ ] ^` since it's using the character codes from the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

```
SELECT char(64 + table.column) FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ascii values:

```
select CHAR(1 + 64);
            ^ that's your 1..26
```